# Can't click links under a DIV

Tags: html, css

I have my logo and its DIV spans 100% of the screen. This means I cannot click on my link because it overlaps them I have tried `z-index`, but not sure what else I could do?

Here's an example of what I mean:

[image: example layout]

HTML

```
<div id="header">
                    <div class="login">
                        <div class="login-text"> 
                            <a class="login-a" href="/index.php?route=account/login">Login</a>
                            |
                            <a class="login-a" href="/index.php?route=account/account">View Account</a>
                            |
                            <a class="login-a" href="/index.php?route=account/logout">Logout</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php if ($logo) { ?>
                    <div id="logo"><a  href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><img id="la-logo" src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></a></div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
```

CSS

```
#la-logo{
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 100%;
  }
 .login{
   width: 290px;
   height: 40px;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: right;
   padding-right: 0px;
   float: right;
display: inline-block;
 }
.login-text{
padding-right: 50px;
padding-top: 10px;
font-family:'quicksandlight';
 }
  .login a{
  color: #000000;
 padding-right: 0px;
 #header #logo {
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
 margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/u5jBB.png

Comment: Instead of an image, please post code to reproduce the issue (a "[mcve]") and explain where the problem is exactly. Tell us what you've researched, debugged, and tried.

Comment: could you provide the code snippet which is not working as expected?

Comment: Why the -2? This is my first ever post...

Comment: `.login a{
  color: #000000;
 padding-right: 0px;`

is not closed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the code, by default a div element with only `width: 100%;` specified in addition to the browsers default styling does not cause it to overlap links.

Just adding the z-index property to an element does not make it work, the element also has to be positioned, you can try `position: relative;`.

But you shouldn't have overlapping elements in that scenario, your code would help us make it better.

Answer (score 5):

You could use **pointer-events: none** for your div to be click-through.

Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/a7vL2ufu/):

**HTML**

```
<button class="bad">click me</button>
<div class="bad"></div>

<button class="good">click me</button>
<div class="good"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.bad {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
}

button.bad {
  position: absolute;
}

div.good {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  height: 100px;
  left: 200px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
}

button.good {
  left: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

and a little bit of **JQuery**

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: it seems over complicated when z-index with positioning solves the issue :)

Comment: If it can resolve the issue then yes, however in cases when that doesn't, it is a good alternative. (note: did not have op's code when written answer)

Comment: yeah, sometimes z-index does not work

Answer (score 2):

z-index doesn't work for elements with a static positionning
Add

```
position: relative;
```

to your links and you should be fine.